# Show that S is an isometry and describe geometrically the action of $S$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $R ∈ L(\mathbb{R}^2)$ e defined by $Rv = Qv$, where $Q$ is given below. Show that $R$ is an isometry and describe
geometrically the action of $R$.

$Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

$R=\begin{bmatrix}1/3&\sqrt{3}/2\\\sqrt{3}/2&1/3\end{bmatrix}$

I saw this question in our book and was wondering how to approach the problem. I know what isomeric generally means but I don't know how to apply it to questions like this.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Well, what does "isometry" means? Also, what is $S$ (which appears in the title) here? Why you write $R = \begin{bmatrix}\tfrac13&\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}2 \\ \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}2&\tfrac13\end{bmatrix}$ once you say that $R : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is defined by $Rv = Qv$?

Comment: An operator S e L(V)  is called an isometry ||sv|| =||v|| for all veV. and what you wrote is correct. that's what the practice problem says.

Comment: I think that the letter "$R$" below the matrix $Q$ should be "$Q$" as well. And, all that you need to do is just verify that $\| Rv \| = \|v\|$, where $v = \begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @azif00 its matrix R

Comment: how to do that though these are 2x2 matrix not 1x2 and how to verify can you please give me a hint

Comment: $R$ is the linear operator on $\mathbb R^2$ (so $R$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ and not a $2 \times 2$ matrix) that sends every $v = \begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^2$ to $Rv = Qv = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} v_2\\v_1 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @azif00 ok understood thanks. Then whats the use of Q's I know maybe its a dumb question just so lost